# How to stop transition animation on clear activity stack android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-intent

A white screen blinks for few milliseconds when I simply go from login activity to Main activity with following clear back stack code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

If I just make the startActivity  without Flags (or say without clear backstack)

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

It doesn't blink with white screen.

But I have to clear back stack and start a new activity with NO transition animation. So it doesn't blink/appear in white screen for few milliseconds.

Looking forward to get a perfect answer soon. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `noHistory="true"` for login activity in the manifest and start `HomeActivity` without any flags. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I can't make nohistory=true to login due to some reason. Got to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If you want to clear the backstack (and assuming your login `Activity` is the only one in the stack), just `finish` the current Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
finish();
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is likely the cause of the flash since it requires you to create a whole new "task" (which is a collection of Activities with a given history) rather than just reusing the current one. It's almost like navigating to another app at that point.

Comment: I understand why it's happening/behaving like this but got resolve it anyhow. There are two login/security screens bdw. So I can finish the second calling activity. But the first login screen willl be there in stack.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Well if you've resolved this issue yourself, you should either update your question or post your own solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the question that startActivity without using flags makes no blink and showing white screen.

So I choose that.

Now the problem is to clear the stack of 1st Login activity when I am into Main Activity.

I resolved it by setting the context of Login activity into Application class using setter and getter method.

And Whenever You reached to Main Activity. It will check whether you have the context in Application class by getter method.

If it's a yes and is a login activity then make the context.finish which will clear the back-stack by removing the login activity from Main Activity. And set null value to setter in Application class.

Feel free to share any concern regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like you're deliberately setting up a memory leak. I'd strongly recommend looking for a different solution. Have you tried just using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and omitting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? This problem can be absolutely solved with the right flags, it's just a question of which ones.

Comment: You should also consider that maybe the intent flags are doing their jobs properly and maybe the blinking is actually a symptom of something : doing a long operation on the main thread for example. It is extremely common to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and most people do not see this issue. So it points to potentially something slightly different.

Comment: Don't do setting activity context in manifest at first place. It's a potential memory leak.

Comment: @BrianYencho I am not sure Why It would leak memory if I am removing the activity context in the next Activity

Comment: Because you are assuming that will always work and that it will always be the same reference. There are potentially circumstances involving rotations and other configuration changes in which that Activity reference isn't the same as the one currently in the stack. Or there are potential problems with process death in which that reference is cleared and therefore it's not available to call "finish" on. It simply isn't safe for a number of reasons to hold an Activity reference in that way.